# How to name a image using the date and time using the imwrite?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opencv

I really wanted to save multiple images but i want to name it using the date and time as their filenames. Can somebody tell me what to do with this code below:

```
//Saving Image
            Mat save_img; cap >> save_img;
            char buffer[20];
            char dateStr[20];
            char timeStr[20];
            _strdate(dateStr);
            _strtime(timeStr);

            if(save_img.empty())
            {
              std::cerr << "Something is wrong with the webcam, could not get frame." << std::endl;
            }
            // Save the frame into a file
            sprintf(buffer,"Cap %s%s.jpg",dateStr,timeStr);
            imwrite(buffer, save_img); // A JPG FILE IS BEING SAVED

            }
```

The code above doesn't save any file images so its not working but somehow it is coded correctly. It is very slow when running, I don't know why.
This is just a part of my code i am working on. Please comment if you know to how improve this one.

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you are using.

Comment: opencv tag would be helpful, too

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and stumbled upon this Reddit post:
http://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/1e4s39/opencv_cant_use_imwrite_dont_understand_error/

So in order to save files with date and time in the filename, one has to make sure to delete all ":" symbols from the string!

```
std::string filename;
std::replace(filename.begin(), filename.end(), ':', '_');
```